# My swap smart contract doesn't seem to swap the tokens

Tags: solidity, avalanche, avax, fuji

I have made a smart contract on Avalanche Fuji chain to test swapping tokens. When I call the smart contract on Remix, my AVAX gets sent, but I never get the USDC I am supposed to get for my AVAX. I don't really understand.

Here is the transaction ID: 0x370c34b209eec673181d928f4f8c1a1a992df9582b45db7af8d6023f07111ceb.

Look at the transaction here: https://subnets-test.avax.network/c-chain/tx/0x370c34b209eec673181d928f4f8c1a1a992df9582b45db7af8d6023f07111ceb

This is the address for WAVAX: 0xd00ae08403B9bbb9124bB305C09058E32C39A48c

USDC: 0x5425890298aed601595a70AB815c96711a31Bc65

Pangolin Router: 0x2D99ABD9008Dc933ff5c0CD271B88309593aB921

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

interface IRouter {
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[]
 calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

interface IWAVAX {
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external;

function approve(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
}

contract Swapper {

address private wavax; // WAVAX Address
address private router; // Swap Router Address

constructor(address _wavax_address, address _router){
    wavax = _wavax_address;
    router = _router;
}

function swap(uint256 amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, uint256 amountIn, uint256 deadline) external {
    // We transfer the wavax from the user (msg.sender) to this contract.
    IWAVAX(wavax).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountIn);
    // We approve the router as a spender for our Wavax.
    IWAVAX(wavax).approve(router, amountIn);
    // We do the swap using the router.
    IRouter(router).swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, path, msg.sender, deadline);
}

receive() external payable {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things that might cause trouble

1. Did you set the arguments values correctly? if not you can get frontrun for 100% or it just won't work. How are you calculating the following values?

```
    amountIn, amountOutMin, path, etc...
```

2.An approval must be given before the first transferFrom

3.Are you sure this pangolin router uses the swapExactTokensForTokens function because the contract isn't verified?

4.Something could be wrong with the wavax token code